# How to define type of object in Redland R RDF triples

Tags: r, rdf, triples, redland

I'm trying to use the Redland R RDF implementation to construct a simple RDF store but am having problems writing non-literal triples. In code, after setting up `world` and `model`, whilst the literal triple

```
addStatement(model,
             new("Statement",world,
                 "a:John","b:likes","a:Jane"))
```

gives the expected

```
<a:John> <b:likes> "a:Jane"
```

the code

```
addStatement(model,
             new("Statement",world,
                 "a:Sian","b:likes","a:John",objectType="blank"))
```

gives `_:a:John` instead of `<a:John>`

```
<a:Sian> <b:likes> _:a:John
```

which does not match in the fold in the SPARQL

```
select ?a ?b where {?a <b:likes> ?x. ?x <b:likes> ?b.}
```

What am I doing wrong here? Note that this application does not *per se* look at any delegated databases  as I'm just using the triples to exploit the logical power of a SPARQL query. Had originally done this in another package but am trying to move to Redland for technical reasons.

Comment: Try `objectType="uri"` instead.

Comment: perfect. That's it. If you post that as an answer, I can accept it.

Comment: Please post the answer yourself and accept it. Probably you could paste a link to the documentation (I guess [this](https://github.com/cran/redland/blob/master/R/Statement.R#L68) link) or even to the [RDF 1.1](https://www.w3.org/TR/rdf11-concepts/#section-triples) specification. It seems that Redland RDF R library is really not very well documented.

Answer (score 1):

With many thanks to Stanislav's comment above, the answer is simply to set objectType to "uri". This is not well documented in the R, but looking at the definition of a `Statement` object, line 68 on [Github](https://github.com/cran/redland/blob/master/R/Statement.R#L68), gives the relevant options and defaults.